# How can I tell what kind of partition I have? (ext2,3,4)?

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I read this article talking about chopping boot-time in half with e4rat, but in order to do so your partition has to be ext4. How can you check what kind of partition you have?

Thanks in advance
zarnaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this...

If you search for *disk* in Dash, you can examine the layout of your partitions for any hard-drives you have installed.

For example:

[image]

This image on my laptop shows that I have a mixture of ext4 and ntfs partitions.

If you double click each visible partition in Nautilus and then run in a terminal `df -T` you can see the ext type for each partition that is mounted.

For example

```
dad@emachineubuntu:~$ df -T
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5     ext4    99520000  76240232  18224384  81% /
udev      devtmpfs     3956048         4   3956044   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs     1586240      1188   1585052   1% /run
none         tmpfs        5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none         tmpfs     3965592       592   3965000   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3  fuseblk    58554680  43349156  15205524  75% /media/eMachines
/dev/sda7     ext4    65423132   3349996  58749744   6% /media/5e4ea9ba-
```

N.B. the NTFS partition is shown as *fuseblk*

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Disk Utility app from the dash, look for your root partition (it should be named root.disk) and look for the "type" label. Now you can see which type of partition you have.

Answer (score 1):

Easyest way is to open gParted. There you have an easy overview of your partitions.